# Connect a mule4 client to a python websockets server

Tags: python, websocket, mule, mulesoft

I have a python websockets server and im trying to connect to it via mulesoft.
The connection is established and mule is able to send something to the server but is not able to receive the answer. I read that although its an outbound socket we need an "On inbound message" to receive the message.
The python server logs all the messages until "await completed" so the "websocket.send(reply)" is executed. The problem I have is: how do I configure the "on outbound message" or the "on inbound message" to receive this reply and log it?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Python server:

```
import asyncio

import websockets


# create handler for each connection


async def handler(websocket, path):
    print("client just connnected")
    data = await websocket.recv()
    print("data:" + data)
    reply = f"Data recieved as:  {data}!"
    await websocket.send(reply)
    print("await completed")


start_server = websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 8000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Mule client:

[Mule client screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyFgJ.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:sockets="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sockets"
    xmlns:os="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:websocket="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/websocket" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/websocket http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/websocket/current/mule-websocket.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os/current/mule-os.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sockets http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sockets/current/mule-sockets.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="71f64084-8631-411b-ac3d-72753e0420dc" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <websocket:config name="WebSockets_Config" doc:name="WebSockets Config" doc:id="8b7e2026-1a43-40a5-b6f6-57f1e810e1e9" >
        <websocket:connection >
            <websocket:client-settings host="localhost" port="8000"/>
        </websocket:connection>
    </websocket:config>
    <websocket:config name="WebSockets_serve_config" doc:name="WebSockets Config" doc:id="6bb1f71b-fcb1-4bc7-bbbc-b3167d952092" >
        <websocket:connection >
            <websocket:server-settings listenerConfig="HTTP_Listener_config" />
        </websocket:connection>
    </websocket:config>
    <flow name="scorewsclientFlow" doc:id="44652992-9b94-45e2-9942-3e965fdd4fd2" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="76ea16ed-0f8d-4fe0-996d-750b65d81af3" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/connect"/>
        <set-variable value='#[correlationId ++ "-" ++ attributes.queryParams.client_name]' doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="b9f3920f-1244-465b-aaeb-820596206708" variableName="socketid"/>
        <os:store doc:name="Store" doc:id="8143c9a5-af90-46b8-b158-ba2cfed6fce9" key="#[attributes.queryParams.client_name]">
            <os:value ><![CDATA[#[vars.socketid]]]></os:value>
        </os:store>
        <websocket:open-outbound-socket doc:name="Open outbound socket" doc:id="f0d6d235-2c74-4546-921e-8fe9e12c084a" config-ref="WebSockets_Config" path="/open" socketId="#[vars.socketid]"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="93d5e10f-babf-45bf-93f5-bf2c8e047bf1">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    message: "Connection successful"
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
    <flow name="scorewsclientFlow1" doc:id="690325a5-c162-49f8-b056-e02b0150e999" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="6496973b-be0e-4a94-96c6-803951688f5f" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/send"/>
        <set-variable value="#[attributes.queryParams.client_name]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="3b6e1023-a9b9-49fa-a11d-67c54829246b" variableName="client_name" />
        <os:retrieve doc:name="Retrieve" doc:id="7727bec0-8258-4b18-934f-269d9cbd1f1c" key="#[vars.client_name]"/>
        <set-variable value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="6ab9d0d9-9d67-4af6-8a87-b2d5aa8eed04" variableName="socketid"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Message-subscription" doc:id="68c440ae-b88a-476a-a696-393caa79b063">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    client_name: vars.client_name,
    match_id: "12345"
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <websocket:send doc:name="Send" doc:id="5f0ba317-3025-421b-9837-dd5bddeabdc7" config-ref="WebSockets_Config" socketId="#[vars.socketid]">
        </websocket:send>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="cde387c5-cd58-4f78-9a41-49076be68fff">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    socketid: vars.socketid,
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
    <flow name="scorewsclientFlow3" doc:id="42b0a800-a027-41f7-a459-3958040eed1a" >
        <websocket:inbound-listener doc:name="On New Inbound Message" doc:id="706960f7-3f04-48a2-b95c-a66f9c62edd6" config-ref="WebSockets_serve_config" path="/"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="5c99e3ae-f829-4f35-ac70-239002ea32f0" message="#[payload]"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: The screenshot is redundant and doesn't provide any useful information. Please avoid using screenshots in questions unless related to UI. Also MuleSoft is a company name. Your applications is deployed in Mule runtime, which is only one of MuleSoft products. It is not correct to say "Connect a mulesoft client". Connect a client application deployed in Mule 4 would be correct.

Comment: Have you tested your server with any other client? What is exactly the question?

Comment: How do I configure the Mule 4 client application to receive the response from the python server? The python server logs all the messages until "await completed" so the "websocket.send(reply)" is executed. The problem I have is: how do I configure the "on outbound message" or the "on inbound message" to receive this reply and log it?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- If the mule app is just a client (ie: it's not serving/handling new inbound WS connections), you don't need to configure a websocket server inside the mule app.
- If you want to listen for the responses of the messages you sent from the Mule app, you have to configure a 'websocket:outbound-listener' instead of a 'websocket:inbound-listener'.

Try changing the inbound listener for an outbound one and it should work fine.

You can also check the official documentation for some working examples: https://docs.mulesoft.com/websockets-connector/1.0/websockets-connector-examples